# Get date/time for request history

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the below script which pulls all URL redirect history. Is there a way I can get the date and time of when these redirects were effected?

```
r = requests.get(url)
for h in r.history:
    print (h.url)
print (r.url)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get from the headers of the history objs.
like.

```
r = requests.get(url)
for h in r.history:
    print (h.url)
    print (h.headers.get("date"))
print (r.url)
```